# Bad decrypt error in Visual Studio DevOps pipeline (used to work)

Tags: azure-devops, openssl, azure-pipelines

My Visual Studio DevOps pipeline has recently stopped working.
The error is with an OpenSSL decrypt step:

`digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:537:`

My build pipeline worked as recently as 10 Jan (and I haven't changed the definition). That build used the same version of the OpenSSL task as today (1.142.2)

Full output from DevOps:

```
2019-01-28T23:52:54.3117192Z ==============================================================================
2019-01-28T23:52:54.3117249Z Task         : Decrypt File (OpenSSL)
2019-01-28T23:52:54.3117286Z Description  : A thin utility task for file decryption using OpenSSL.
2019-01-28T23:52:54.3117338Z Version      : 1.142.2
2019-01-28T23:52:54.3117375Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-01-28T23:52:54.3117408Z Help         : 
2019-01-28T23:52:54.3117441Z ==============================================================================
2019-01-28T23:52:54.7074315Z [command]C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\openssl.exe des3 -d -in D:\a\1\s\signingCertificatesEncrypted\my-release-key.keystore.enc -out D:\a\1\s\signingCertificatesDecrypted\my-release-key.keystore -pass pass:***
2019-01-28T23:52:57.4818326Z *** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
2019-01-28T23:52:57.4818778Z Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
2019-01-28T23:52:57.5070499Z bad decrypt
2019-01-28T23:52:57.5071102Z 25769902144:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:537:
```

Comment: I've got exactly the same error since today for a specific branch in my project. However, with old branches, it is still working... But the `.enc` has not changed... No idea what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same issue since this morning.
After a lot of debbuging, we found out that the problem is from the default "MessageDigest" of the "Decrypt File" task, that is not always the same.

Instead of creating a "Decrypt File" task, create a "PowerShell" task, with a powershell script containing:

`openssl des3 -md md5 -d -in signingCertificatesEncrypted\my-release-key.keystore.enc -out signingCertificatesDecrypted\my-release-key.keystore -pass pass:$Env:CERT_PASS`

Don't forget to add a `CERT_PASS` environment variable.

If it does not work, try switch `-md md5` to `-md XXX` (with other MessageDigest type)

Comment: worked great, thanks. Had to replace pass:$Env:CERT_PASS with pass:$(CERT_PASS) because I have it configured as a secret variable (took too long to figure that out!)